# Serve jQuery UI from Google's CDN or as a local copy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

while it's better to serve jQuery from Google's CDN jQuery UI is a different beast. My local modified copy weighs 60kb and the one in Google's CDN ~200kb.

- Are there any numbers on how many sites uses the CDN? (read: how many users have it in their cache). How do I know/calculate if it's better to serve it locally?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Coming late to the party here, but allowing for gzip compression, you're basically comparing a download of ~51k from Google's CDN (the 197.14k content becomes 51.30k on-the-wire) vs. ~15.5k from your own servers (assuming your 60k file gzips at the same ratio as the full jQuery UI file does, and that you have gzip compression enabled). This takes us into a complex realm of:

- pre-existing cache copy
- latency
- transfer time
- number of requests
- proper cache headers

And the answer to your question is a big: **It depends, try each of them and measure the result in a real world scenario.**

#### Pre-Existing Cache Copy

If a first-time visitor to your site has previously been to a site using jQuery UI from Google's CDN and it's still in their cache, that wins hands down. Full stop. No need to think about it any further. Google uses appropriate caching headers and the browser doesn't even have to send the request to the server, provided you link to a *fully-specified version* of jQuery UI (not one of the "any version of 1.8.x is fine" URLs — if you ask for [jQuery UI 1.8.16](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js), Google will return a resource that can be cached for up to a year, but if you ask for [jQuery UI 1.8.x](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js) [e.g., any dot rev of 1.8], that resource is only good for an *hour*).

But let's suppose they haven't...

#### Latency and Transfer Time

Latency is how long it takes to set up the connection to the server, and transfer time is the time actually spent transferring the resource. Using my DSL connection (I'm not very close to my exchange, so I typically get about 4Mbit throughput on downloads; e.g., it's an okay connection, but nothing like what Londoners get, or those lucky FiOS people in the States), in repeated experiments downloading [Google's copy of jQuery UI](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js) I typically spend ~50ms waiting for the connection (latency) and then 73ms doing data transfer (SSL would change that profile, but I'm assuming a non-SSL site here). Compare that with downloading Google's copy of [jQuery itself](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js) (89.52k gzipped to 31.74k), which has the same ~50ms latency followed by ~45ms of downloading. Note how the download time is proportional to the size of the resource (31.74k / 51.30k = 0.61871345, and sure enough, 73ms x 0.61871345 = 45ms), but the latency is constant. So assuming your copy comes in at 15.5k, you could expect (for me) a 50ms latency plus about 22ms of actual downloading. All other things being equal, by hosting your own 60k copy vs. Google's 200k copy, you would save me a whopping 52ms. Let's just say that I wouldn't notice the difference.

All is not equal, however. Google's CDN is highly optimized, location-aware, and very fast indeed. For instance, let's compare downloading jQuery from Heroku.com. I chose them because they're smart people running a significant hosting business (currently using the AWS stack), and so you can expect they've at least spent *some* time optimizing their delivery of static content — and it happens they use a local copy of jQuery for their website; and they're in the U.S. (you'll see why in a moment). If I download jQuery from them (shockingly, they don't appear to have gzip enabled!), the latency is consistently in the 135ms range (with occasional outliers). That's consistently 2.7 times as much latency as to Google's CDN (and my throughput from them is slower, too, roughly half the speed; perhaps they only use AWS instances in the U.S., and since I'm in the UK I'm further away from them).

The point here being that latency may well wash out any benefit you get from the smaller file size.

#### Number of Requests

If you have **any** JavaScript files you're going to host locally, your users are still going to have to get those. Say you have 100k of your own script for your site. If you use Google's CDN, your users have to get 200k of jQuery UI from Google and 100k of your script from you. The browser may put those requests in parallel (barring your using `async` or `defer` on your `script` tags, the browser has to *execute* the scripts in strict document order, but that doesn't mean it can't download them in parallel). Or it may well not.

As we've established that for non-mobile users, at these sizes the actual data transfer time doesn't really matter that much, you may find that taking your local jQuery UI file and combining it with your own script, thus requiring only one download rather than two, may be more efficient even despite the Google CDN goodness.

This is the old "At most one HTML file, one CSS file, and one JavaScript file" rule. Minimizing HTTP requests is a Good Thing<sup>TM</sup>. Similarly, if you can use sprites rather than individual images for various things, that helps keep image requests down.

#### Proper Cache Headers

If you're hosting your own script, you'll want to be absolutely sure it's cacheable, which means paying attention to the cache headers. Google's CDN basically doesn't trust HTTP/1.0 caches (it sets the `Expires` header to the current date/time), but does trust HTTP/1.1 caches — the overwhelming majority — because it sends a `max-age` header (of a year for fully-specified resources). I'm guessing they have a reason for that, you might consider following suit.

Since you want to change your own scripts sometimes, you'll want to put a version number on them, e.g. "my-nifty-script-1.js" and then "my-nifty-script-2.js", etc. That's so you can set long `max-age` headers, but know that when you update your script, your users will get the new one. (This goes for CSS files, too.) **Do not** use the query string for the versioning, put the number actually in the resource name.

Since your HTML presumably changes regularly, you probably want short expirations on that, but of course it totally depends on your content.

#### Conclusion

**It depends.** If you don't want to combine your script with your local copy of jQuery UI, you're probably better off using Google for jQuery UI. If you're happy to combine them, you'll want to do real-world experiments either way to make your own decision. It's entirely possible other factors will wash this out and it won't really matter. If you haven't already, it's worth reviewing Yahoo's and Google's website speed advice pages:

- [Yahoo! *Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Website*](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)
- [Google's *Let's make the web faster* site](http://code.google.com/speed/)

Answer (score 9):

Google's CDN of jquery UI weighs in at 51 Kb:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js

The [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) uses a fallback for jquery loading:

```
<!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, with a protocol relative URL; fall back to local if necessary -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.5.1.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
```

You can apply it to jquery ui:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery.ui || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
```

You load the CDN version then check for the existence of jquery ui (you can't guarantee 100% up-time for any CDN). If jquery ui doesn't exist, fall back to your local. In this way, if they have it already in their cache, you are good to go. If they don't and the CDN can't be retrieved for any reason, your good to go with your local. Fail safe.

Answer (score 2):

I think size comparisons miss the point of the CDN. By serving a copy of jQuery (or other library) from a public, commonly-used CDN, many users will have a cached copy of the library before they arrive at your site. When they do, the effective size of the download is 0KB compared to 60KB from your server.

Google's CDN is the most widely used, so you will have the best chance of a cache hit if you reference it.

For numbers comparing the various CDNs please see [this article](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/).

For what it's worth, the minified version of Google's jQuery copy is much smaller than the size you mentioned.

Comment: *"For what it's worth, the minified version of Google's jQuery copy is much smaller than the size you mentioned."* jQuery **UI**, not jQuery. Google's [minified version of jQuery UI](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js) is 197.14k; @myxospsm's "~200kb" is pretty close. :-) Naturally, gzip compression helps there, coming in at ~51k on-the-wire, but comparing apples to apples and assuming similar gzip compression, that's ~51k for the Google version vs. ~15.5k for his (gzipping his 60k).

Answer (score 1):

I would say what matter is the load you have on your server. For the user it doesn't really matter if they are downloading it from your server or from google's server. These days there is enough bandwidth for 140kb to be easy to ignore on the user's side.

Now the really question is if you made changes to jQuery UI. If yes then you should serve your own copy. If not, then it's ok to serve google's. Because after all what you are aiming to is to lower load on your side.

And besides the caching doesn't happen just on the user's browser, but also on content distribution nodes that they are accessing. So it's safe to say that google's copy is cached almost for sure.

Comment: I think using the most popular CDN for 'general' scripts has a good pro of having users already have a cached version even before they access the site for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

With sizes this small, what matters is number of http requests for a first-time visitor to your site.

If for example your site has script combining and minification configured so the entire script for a first time visitor is either one request or included in html itself, using your local copy is better because even a cached copy of JqueryUI isn't faster than all the script for the site showing up at once (the cached call still has to go out and check for Modified).

If you don't have a good script combining and minification setup (so you were going to send jqueryui separately, either from your site or elsewhere), use outside caches wherever possible.